How to convert string to datetime in PostgreSQL
I have a column named cancel_date in my table, which stores date in varchar datatype and have some empty rows:



id
cancel_date




111
2024-03-27T11:27:20.215419+00:00


222
NULL


333
2024-02-23T22:02:41.671511+00:00


444
NULL



So, i need to transform date values from cancel_date to TIMESTAMP format. i use TO_TIMESTAMP(cancel_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.US+TZ'), but got this error: Failed to tokenize string [Y] at offset [0]
How to deal with Null values using TO_TIMESTAMP()?
UPD also tried to cut msc by SUBSTRING() and got same error -  Failed to tokenize string [Y] at offset [0]
select
id,
cancel_date,
SUBSTRING(cancel_date FROM 1 FOR 19),
CASE 
    WHEN cancel_date IS NOT NULL then
        TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING(cancel_date FROM 1 FOR 19),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
    ELSE NULL 
END AS formatted_timestamp
from mytable


What client application or library are you issuing this query from? Where exactly are you getting that error message? Your example seems to be perfectly correct, PostgreSQL-wise: demo.

Since you are working with dates/timestamps in ISO8601 format, all you have to do is cast the string; it works like a charm.
SELECT id, cancel_date::timestamptz
FROM (
    VALUES
    (111, '2024-03-27T11:27:20.215419+00:00'),
    (222, NULL),
    (333, '2024-02-23T22:02:41.671511+00:00'),
    (444, NULL)
) T(id, cancel_date)

Alternatively, the TO_TIMESTAMP pattern you can apply is like so:
SELECT id, TO_TIMESTAMP(cancel_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.USTZH:TZM')
FROM ...

This is documented in the Postgres documentation. As is written there:

TZ only works in TO_CHAR, therefore you need to use TZH and TZM.
TZH can match a signed number, so no need to put a + or - before it (and in fact, you must not put one).

BTW, both solutions work for NULL values.

Having problem with cancel_date::timestamptz (mismatched input ':'), should i use cast() insted of ::?

No, it is supposed to work as is; I tested the query on my computer and it does work. Saying you are having problem is not precise enough for me to answer anyway. Is it an error message you are getting? Which one if it is? What else if not? Anyway, I added a working pattern for TO_TIMESTAMP as a backup.

yes, i got this error (SQL Error [7]: Query failed (#20240516_113530_33531_7vfn3): Failed to tokenize string [Y] at offset [0]) exactly after executing query with case when construction and TO_TIMESTAMP()

Postgres errors are 5 alphanumerical characters (see here) so SQL Error [7] is most likely an error in the client or something, not an error in postgres. Try CREATE TABLE Whatever AS SELECT ... and see if the fact no data is being returned removes the error. That would confirm my point if it disappears.

Same error... Anyway, thanks a lot for helping me to choose a direction for my problem solving, most likely it's really on my client's side

I assure you I ran the query on a Postgres database v16.2 and it works. Do you have https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html on your computer so that you eliminate the client variable? BTW, if you want to give a chance to someone else to answer, you should mention your client and the full error message (including error code) in your question. It is absent right now and I just assumed it was an error I had never seen when I answered. Having the extra information would have allowed me (and others) to point to a better direction super fast.

Thank you! I'll keep it in mind for my new questions.

Works for non-ISO formats as well: select '05/16/2024 07:35'::timestamp; 2024-05-16 07:35:00.  You do need to be aware of DateStyle setting from here postgresql.conf client formatting 20.11.2. Locale and Formatting. More information here Date/time types Table 8.15. Date Order Conventions.

It seems that the value NULL is a text value rather than null. So here it is:
select id, nullif(cancel_date, 'NULL')::timestamptz
from the_table;


Good idea but no, the error message generated in this case is much more explicit than the one in the question: ERROR:  Value must be an integer.invalid value "NULL" for "YYYY" / ERROR:  invalid value "NULL" for "YYYY"

But the query above works with no errors at all. Fiddle
